# Next without For Error while formatting a worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA. I am trying to run a formatting check on a sheet.

The error is `Next without For error`. What I am trying to do is to check columns H and O from rows number 33 to 58 for number formatting error. It shows error at "Next n".

The code is like this:

```
Public Sub PercentageCheck()
Dim CTRYname As String
Dim x As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim m As Integer


For n = 1 To 13

CTRYname = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Country lookup").Range("A1").Offset(n, 0).Value

For m = 33 To 58
For x = 8 To 15

If x = 9 Or x = 10 Or x = 11 Or x = 12 Or x = 13 Or x = 14 Then
GoTo Names
Else
wkbCurr.Sheets(CTRYname).Activate
    If IsNumeric(wkbCurr.Sheets(CTRYname).Cells(x, m).Value) Then
        If wkbCurr.Sheets(CTRYname).Cells(x, m).Value > 9.99 Then
            wkbCurr.Sheets(CTRYname).Cells(x, m).Value = ">999%"
        ElseIf wkbCurr.Sheets(CTRYname).Cells(x, m).Value < -9.99 Then
            wkbCurr.Sheets(CTRYname).Cells(x, m).Value = "<-999%"
        End If
    End If


 Names:
 Next x


Next m


Next n

End Sub
```

Can you help with suggestions for a better way to check it.

Comment: `For x = 8 to 15 Step 7` would seem more sensible and avoid the weird `If` and the (not really needed anyway) `goto`

Comment: Thanks a lot. But it is still not converting any %age > than 999% into the string ">999%".

Comment: [This](http://www.oaltd.co.uk/Indenter/Default.htm) is a great tool for indenting code and seeing where items are missing, or at least presenting it in a prettier (and more readable) format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Second question first: `suggest a better way to check it.`
Answer: be diligent with indenting.  This easily revleals the missing line of code

```
Public Sub PercentageCheck()
    Dim CTRYname As String
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim m As Integer

    For n = 1 To 13
        CTRYname = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Country lookup").Range("A1").Offset(n, 0).Value
        For m = 33 To 58
            For x = 8 To 15
                If x = 9 Or x = 10 Or x = 11 Or x = 12 Or x = 13 Or x = 14 Then
                    GoTo Names
                Else
                    wkbCurr.Sheets(CTRYname).Activate
                    If IsNumeric(wkbCurr.Sheets(CTRYname).Cells(x, m).Value) Then
                        If wkbCurr.Sheets(CTRYname).Cells(x, m).Value > 9.99 Then
                            wkbCurr.Sheets(CTRYname).Cells(x, m).Value = ">999%"
                        ElseIf wkbCurr.Sheets(CTRYname).Cells(x, m).Value < -9.99 Then
                            wkbCurr.Sheets(CTRYname).Cells(x, m).Value = "<-999%"
                        End If
                    End If
'  ---> Missing End If
Names:
            Next x
        Next m
    Next n
End Sub
```

BTW, the `GoTo Names` is not necassary in this code.  And neither is `wkbCurr.Sheets(CTRYname).Activate`.  Just leave them out and the code works the same.

---

**Update:**

Based on your comment and the bug it revealed, I suggest you use more meaningful variable names.  This will help avoid this kind of error.  Also, prudent use of `With` can make your code more readable (and faster)

Here's a refactored version to demonstrate

```
Public Sub PercentageCheck()
    Dim CTRYname As String
    Dim col As Integer
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim rw As Integer

    For n = 1 To 13
        CTRYname = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Country lookup").Range("A1").Offset(n, 0).Value
        With wkbCurr.Sheets(CTRYname)
            For rw = 33 To 58
            For col = 8 To 15
                If col < 9 Or col > 14 Then
                    With .Cells(rw, col)
                        If IsNumeric(.Value) Then
                            If .Value > 9.99 Then
                                .Value = ">999%"
                            ElseIf .Value < -9.99 Then
                                .Value = "<-999%"
                            End If
                        End If
                    End With
                End If
            Next col, rw
        End With
    Next n
End Sub
```

Comment: Thx.  What better way is there to find the bug!

Comment: @chris-neilson Agreed... but for a small snippet like this I just counted opening vs. closing (as per my updated answer), but you're right... if this were code under my control I would've just fixed the indenting as per "best practice".

Comment: Thanks Chris, But still not working as intended. The values in column H and O are in percentages but they are not getting corrected if its greater than 999%. Also thanks a lot for the Goto tip.

Comment: That because you are referencing columns 33:58 and rows 8:15.  `.Cells` syntax is `.Cells(row, column)`

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an `END IF` for your `If x = 9 Or x = 10 Or x = 11 Or x = 12 Or x = 13 Or x = 14 Then ... Else ...`

Indent your code to improve readability and this sort of thing will become somewhat self-evident.  @chris-neilsen's example is excellent.

Counting opening statements, compared to closing statements will help at a pinch (and is what I did to debug your code in this instance).

Using an IDE that highlights corresponding start/end symbols would also help you (but I'm not sure what IDE's are available for VBA macros... if anything).